# Trying to wrap my head around setting instance variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby by reading *Programming Ruby, the Pragmatic Programmers Guide.*  I really like how terse the syntax is.

I can't understand the role of the `=` in setter method names:

```
def price=(new_price)
    @price = new_price
end
```

How is that function definition any different than this:

```
def price(new_price)
```

What difference does `=` make? The book says it makes direct assignment possible. But it's already possible with a normal setter method that does not have a `=`... ?

Here's the rest of the class:

```
class BookInStock
    attr_reader    :isbn
    attr_accessor  :price

    def initialize(isbn, price)
        @isbn = isbn
        @price = Float(price)
    end
end

book.price = book.price * 0.75
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gives you 'syntactical sugar' to write code as follows:

```
class Book
    price=(new_price)
       @price = new_price
       # do something else
    end
end

book = Book.new

book.price = 1
```

This code will be translated to

```
book.price=(1)
```

Actually `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor` methods generate *setter* (`price=`) methods for your class (`attr_reader` and `attr_accessor` generates *getter* methods as well).
 So your `BookInStock` class is similar to:

```
class BookInStock
    def isbn val
        @isbn = val
    end

    def price val
        @price
    end
    def price= val
        @price = val
    end

    def initialize(isbn, price)
        @isbn = isbn
        @price = Float(price)
    end
end
```

You need to write methods with `=` only if you are going to add some logic into it (like validation). In other cases just use `attr_writer` or `attr_accessor`.

Comment: Ahh! I get it! So it allows you to make instance variable assignments outside of the class without having to call the setter method explicitly, like in Java, for example?

Comment: I understand what you meant now. Thanks. It's handy way to include extra logic into the method. Otherwise we can rely on `attr_accessor` to do the trick. Thanks! The syntax of Ruby is a little strange for me, but I really like how clean it is.

Comment: You define your setter method with name that ends with `=` and then call this setter with the syntax similar to variable assignment. And your setter method assigns value to the instance variable.