# What is the difference between def func(var) and def func=(var)?

Tags: ruby

In a class definition, what is the difference between these two methods?

```
def func(var)
...
end

def func=(var)
...
end
```

Is there any, or is one of them not valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain some things about reader/writer AKA getter/setter methods in Ruby:

Ruby doesn't force us to use `=` in the method definition for a setter. We get to choose whether the method has one.

Consider this:

```
class Foo

  # automagically creates:
  #   .v
  #   .v=
  attr_accessor :v

  def initialize(v)
    puts "inside initialize(#{ v })"
    @v = v
  end

  def setter(v)
    puts "inside setter(#{ v })" 
    @v = v 
  end

  def setter=(v) 
    puts "inside setter=(#{ v })"
    @v = v 
  end

end

f = Foo.new(1)
puts f.v

f.setter(2)
puts f.v

f.setter = 3
puts f.v

f.setter=(4)
puts f.v

f.v = 5
puts f.v

f.v=(6)
puts f.v
```

Running the code outputs:

```
inside initialize(1)
1
inside setter(2)
2
inside setter=(3)
3
inside setter=(4)
4
5
6
```

The `=` is simply another letter in the method name because Ruby is smart enough to know if it sees `f.setter = 3` it should use the `setter=(v)` method.

Ruby doesn't force using `=` to set a variable, you can decide if it makes more sense to you when you define the method. It is idiomatic that we use `=` because it helps make a setter look like an assignment, removing the urge to name all the setters something like `set_v(v)`.

Comment: OK, now I got it ... thank you very much for the explaination :D

Comment: @RogerNordqvist, no problem. It threw me for a loop when I learned Ruby because I came from other languages that were not that flexible.

Answer (score 6):

Both of them are valid method definitions. But the second one is defining a 'setter' method - you can call this method with the following syntax:

```
obj.func = 123
```

This statement will be translated into

```
obj.func=(123)
```

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616551/158689) where I explain this syntax in a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightement :)

Comment: Either could be a setter, it really depends on what you use the value for. Using `=` makes it fit our idea of what an assignment should look like, but it's really icing on the cake. Other programming styles for other languages would look for the presence of the parameter to decide whether it's a setter vs. a getter.

Comment: @the Tin Man: So the = could be omitted? It says the same thing without the = ?

Comment: @RogerNordqvist, Sure you can omit it. `=` is not magical, it is part of the name of the method, just like using `?` or `!` in some methods. You don't *have* to use it. See "[Accessors](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html)" for more information. It is idiomatic in Ruby to use `=` with a setter just like using `?` with something that returns a Boolean true/false, but nothing says you have to use it.

Comment: @RogerNordqvist, I added an answer explaining what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

These are defining the `getter` and `setter` methods if you will. Say you have a `Person` class with a phone attribute.

```
class Person
  def phone
    @phone
  end

  def phone=(number)
    @phone = number
  end
end
```

Now you could change the phone attribute (managed internally in the `@phone`) by simply setting the property which will invoke the `phone=` method.

```
john = Person.new
john.phone = "123-456-7890"
```

It looks like a property assignment on the outside. Other characters that you can stack at the end of a method name are `?` for boolean getters, `!` for destructive operations. Again, these are just conventions and you're free to use these three characters as you want. However, code simply looks more natural with these symbols around. For example,

```
question.closed?
document.destroy!
```

Comment: You're welcome @Roger. Ruby has one of the nicest syntax compared to most languages :)